# Not source found scala - Maven project

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I have created a scala maven project, I wrote a simple programme scala then I did RunAs -> Maven install, it return Build success, but it dispaly also:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-versions) @ myproject ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.1.3:compile (default) @ myproject ---
[WARNING] No source files found.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.1.3:testCompile (default) @ myproject ---
[WARNING] No source files found.
```

This a sample of the code of the POM:

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Someone can tell where's the problem ?

Comment: Where are your source files? If they are not in `src/main/scala`, relative to your project's root directory, _Maven_ is not going to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the scala-maven-plugin search for source files (**/*.scala) under :

- src/main/java (or the directory you configure as sourceDirectory)
- src/main/scala

and for test under:

- src/test/java (or the directory you configure as testSourceDirectory)
- src/test/scala

So your configuration seems correct, if you store your files *.scala under those directory.

PS: For a new project I encourage you to use a recent version of the plugin (the latest should be 3.4.1)